# Error "Could not deduce instance"; two contexts?

Tags: haskell

I was reading https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/gb7f9l/design_trade_offs_for_different_application/fp5kmjv and trying something out. I ran into an error I don't understand.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableSuperClasses #-}

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Reader.Class
import Data.Kind

newtype Y = Y { unY :: Int }

data Services c = Services
  { service1 :: forall m. c m => m Int
  , object :: forall m. c m => m Y  
  }

myServices :: c ~ (MonadReader (Services c)) => Services c
myServices = Services
  { service1 = unY <$> join (asks object)
  , object = pure $ Y 2
  }
```

The errors all go eg.

```
    * Could not deduce (Functor m) arising from a use of `<$>'
      from the context: c ~ MonadReader (Services c)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   myServices :: forall (c :: (* -> *) -> Constraint).
                                 (c ~ MonadReader (Services c)) =>
                                 Services c
      or from: c m
        bound by a type expected by the context:
                   forall (m :: * -> *). c m => m Int
```

However, it seems to me that

```
(c m, c ~ (MonadReader (Services c))
```

should mean

```
MonadReader (Services c) m
```

and as

```
Monad m => MonadReader r m where ...
```

then

```
Monad m -- implies Applicative m implies Functor m
```

What have I misunderstood? Is the fact that the two contexts are presented separately relevant somehow - why doesn't it have access to both contexts?

Comment: What can `c` be besides the infinite `MonadReader (Services (MonadReader (Services (MonadReader .....` that will satisfy `c ~ (MonadReader (Services c)`?

Comment: I don't think GHC uses equality constraints to deduce other constraints, does it?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I don't think that answers the question directly? @amalloy If I write instead `myServices :: c ~ Monad => Services c` `myServices = Services { service1 = pure 2; object = pure $ Y 2 }` then it compiles, so it seems to be able to use the equality constraint?